# Mobile app rotates only 3 directions on Ipad

Tags: ipad, html, mobile, css

When the ipad is portrait and the home button at the bottom and the camera at the top, the app does not rotate.
But all other directions rotate perfectly, landscape and the other portrait (when the camera on botton and home button on top)

I don't know what causes this problem.

By the way the app is HTML5/Css3 and the Ipad is ipad2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you selected upside down orientation?

It's in the project targets - iPhone/iPad Deployment Info - Supported Device Orientations